# issue with doctrine in symfony 2.0

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to run:

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

but I am constantly getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/Symfony/app/AppKernel.php on line 17
```

Here's my AppKernel.php:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
            new Acme\HelloBundle\AcmeHelloBundle(),
            new Blogger\BlogBundle\BloggerBlogBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

and here's part of the reps file I have related to doctrine:

```
[doctrine-common]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.2.0

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.2.1

[doctrine]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.2.0

[doctrine-fixtures]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git

[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
    target=bundles/Doctrine/Bundle/FixturesBundle
```

I am on Symfony 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Symfony 2.1 compatible version of the Fixtures bundle. Because you are running Symfony 2.0, you need to use the 2.0 compatible branch of the FixturesBundle, which happens to be named 2.0.

Change your deps file:

```
[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
    target=bundles/Doctrine/Bundle/FixturesBundle
    version=origin/2.0
```

And install vendors again.

Comment: so I modified the deps to what you said and changed the settings on AppKernel.php to new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(), but then it still gives me that error

Comment: It's `target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle` anyway check [DoctrineFixturesBundle documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) for *Symfony 2.0*

Answer (score 1):

Did you add this
'Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures' => **DIR**.'/../vendor/doctrine-fixtures/lib',
Do your autoload.php file?